# Prove this combinatorics summation tends to zero.

Tags: probability, limits, summation

I have the following summation:

$$\beta = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{[\frac{n}{k}]} P(N_0=j)P(N_1=n-j)$$

Here, $N_0$ is negative binomial (number of tails required to see a total of $m$ heads when tossing a coin with probability of heads, $p$) and $N_1$ is negative binomial with parameters $m$ and $p-\delta p$ and $k \in (2,3, \dots n-1)$. So,

$$P(N_0=j) = {j+m-1\choose j}p^m(1-p)^j$$
and
$$P(N_1=n-j) = {n-j+m-1\choose j}(p-\delta p)^m(1-p+\delta p)^{n-j}$$

I need to prove:

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \beta = 0$$

I have verified this through explicitly calculating the summation for various values of $p$, $\delta p$. For example:

[image]

Comment: What happens when $\delta=0$

Comment: Then the summation doesn't go to zero. But as long as it's there, even tiny, the summation does go to zero.